# Left Navigation doesn't highlight the selected link

Tags: 2010, navigation

I tried to add some headings and links in left navigation along with HOME link.
The problem i am facing is the Home link is always highlighted wherever u are inside the site.
How can i sort it out ?
Any help or yout thought on this will be much appreciated.

Thanks
Alam

Comment: r u using a custom master page and css? then u will have to modify your css file for this.

Comment: No i m not using custom master page fyi...

Answer (score 1):

access the css file of the master page and look for the following id:

> ## s4-leftpanel-content

Maybe this link can also help you find your way around the master page and Quick launch panels and/or menus.

[Customize Quick launch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms466994%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

Another hint would be too look into the Element using Firebug or a similar tool to single the Home link out and replace it within the Master Page.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

When you visit a page from the quicklaunch bar a css style "selected" is added to your menu li. You can target that with css and stylize it how you'd like.